# Do I have to pay UK tax on earnings from Saudi Arabia

Tags: taxes, united-kingdom, salary, saudi-arabia

I started working in Saudi Arabia on the 31st August 2015, I plan to resign from my job and return to the UK mid July 2015. 
Will I have to pay UK tax on my earnings from Saudi Arabia?

I don't own property in the UK

Comment: Could you clarify the year you started, as 31st August 2015 hasn't happened yet?

Comment: Check with an accountant as it should come under the tax treaty between UK and the Saudis. https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/saudi-arabia-tax-treaties-in-force